# Unwrapping a cube for multiple textures?

Tags: texturing, materials, uv

I want to create a Rectangle with one texture tiling around the sides 3 times and 1 texture on the top and bottom faces. (I am making a wall that needs bricks on the sides and a "top of wall" texture on top)

I want the textures themselves to be one of the bricks (not pre-tiled) and one of the top of the wall, not a single texture.

How can I set up the tile so I can just give it the two textures and it will look right? I don't need a big guide, but I'm a newb to modelling and just need to know the overall idea of it.

My current guess is I need two materials (one for sides and one for the top/bottom) with a specific unwrap for each?

Comment: You guess is right, they key here is using two different materials, one for the bricks one for the "top of wall". Weather you use two materials or not, you don't need two separate unwraps (although you can if you really want to). The unwrap process is pretty irrelevant here, you would only have to take particular care if you were using one single image texture with both bricks and wall texture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  You do need two materials.  I would make two materials, and two material slots.  To make slots you press the plus beside the materials list in the material tab.  You should see another sphere appear in the list.  Then, assign the new material the top image texture.  After that, in  edit mode, select the top faces.  With them selected, then select the new material you just made in the list, then click assign.  Then, you can unwrap the top faces, or you can use your existing unwrap and replace the original image with the new top one.

Don't call yourself a noob.  We all start somewhere. :)

Comment: Thank you for the response! I think now I am mainly just unsure of how to alter a material's UV coordinates within the unwrapped area (Getting the texture in there and actually manipulating it I assume), but you (and Duarte) have given me the main details, so I can probably find a tutorial from here, though if you find time to give a further response it would be appreciated. Thanks again :)

Comment: Got it working! I think what confused me was the unwrapping. I now know that the unwrap itself isn't important. I just made two materials as you said, unwrapped the parts that mattered for the currently selected material and aligned them to a texture loaded in the uv space and assigned it to that material. Just for a bit of extra clarity I did also add the texture to the material too.

Comment: Happy to help.  :)